# How to add data to a predefined object if there is no data?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

If the data is to be removed, I find the element with findIndex and discard it as a null value in isInArray. If there is no such data, how do I add it to the empty element starting from the first element? For example, if the element in the first data is full, it should know that the second element is empty and add it to it.

```
<template>
  <input type="text" v-model="name">
  <input type="text" v-model="surname">
  <button @click="addCustomer"></button>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from "vue";

export default {
  data(){
    return{
      name:null,
      surname:null,
      customers:[{},{},{}],
      currentIndex:null
    }

  },
  methods:{
    addCustomer(){
      let findIndex = this.customers.findIndex((customer) => customer.name === this.name );
      let isInArray = findIndex !== -1;
      if(isInArray){
        Vue.set(this,"currentIndex",findIndex)
        Vue.set(this.customers[this.currentIndex], 'name', null)
    }else{
        // What Should I write here?
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It is not clear what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @YardenBuzaglo It's pretty clear. Look at the customer array. if it is full it will not add data to it, if the next index is empty it will add data to it.

Comment: Do you mean, you want to add customer to list if the name entered in name field not exist, if exist then update the existing customer from the list ?? @oguzcan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understanding from your question, If you want to add customer to list if not in customers by name and if exist then update the existing customer from the list.

Then your code should be like this.

```
<template>
  <input type="text" v-model="name">
  <input type="text" v-model="surname">
  <button @click="addOrUpdateCustomer"></button>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from "vue";

export default {
  data(){
    return{
      name:"",
      surname:"",
      customers:[]      
    }

  },
  methods:{
    addOrUpdateCustomer() {
      const customerAtIndex = this.customers.findIndex(c => c.name === this.name);
      //existing customer
      if(customerAtIndex > -1) {
        // You can update anything here 
        let existingCustomer = this.customers[customerAtIndex];
        existingCustomer.surname = this.surname;
        this.customers[customerAtIndex] = existingCustomer;
      }
      else {
        //new customer 
        this.customers.push({name: this.name, surname: this.surname});
      }
      

    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a misconception here. `customers` is an array of empty objects, it could (or not) contain the information of your customers. But you don't necessarily need to create the empty object as placeholders. `Array` in JS have different methods you can use to achieve what you want. Like [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method to add an element at the end of the array or [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to remove it.

In your example, it could be something like:

```js
addCustomer(){
      let findIndex = this.customers.findIndex((customer) => customer.name === this.name );
      let isInArray = findIndex !== -1;
      if (!isInArray){
        this.customers.push("name", "Nacho")
      }
    }
```

If the customer is not in the array, it is supposed that you want to add it. If IT IS IN THE ARRAY... then it depends on your logic. But you can remove it using `slice` array method.

BTW, there's no need to use the Vue.set method, as the push method is the same for this case (Vue takes care of the new inserted value, so it is reactive).

Comment: The reason I create 3 objects in customer is because I am creating a scenario where I get the customer count before. For this reason, the customer should be in the empty object as much as the count. then I have to place the data in the empty object one by one.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to state above at all @oguzcan

I will be assuming what you are trying to say because it is vague on what you are trying to achieve.

"Creating a scenario where I get the customer count before"
means you only want 3 customers in the array `customers` right? If that's the case why don't you limit the size of the array instead of creating empty objects

"Customer should be in the empty object"
I don't understand this at all, could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Remicaster I have read that this should be done for reactivity. If it's wrong, please let me know.

Comment: I don't understand how this affects reactivity, could you link to the article that stats it does?

Answer (score 0):

As an user above states, I too believe you have a misconception going on.

An array is just a list of customers, the object just contains the attribute of a customer, if there's no customer in the list at the first place, there's no need to add an object.

A cart needs 5 fruits, if the cart is empty, I don't need to add empty strings on the cart.

If an array needs 5 numbers, but if the array is empty, there's no need to add `0`s as a placeholder in the array

You are trying to do something like this

```
const cart = ["", "", "", "", ""] 
const array = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

there's no reason to do this at all.

If you want to limit the size of the array, you can stop the function if the length of the array is at the limit.

For example

```js
// stop the function if the array size is at 3
// means the size limit is 3
if (array.length === 3) return

const addCustomer = () => {
  if (array.length === 3) return
  array.push(value) // replace value with customer or whatever you want to add
}
```

[An example with your implementation (Composition API)](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

[Example in Options API](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNqNUktu4zAMvQqhlQ009mJ2gTOYQY9RdeHaTK3U+kCi0xaB715KloK0RYEuBPDz+Pgo8iL+O9ecFxR70RFqN/eEf6UB6JRxCwG9OzxIQfhGUsB5p+2IMwdMr1GK3yDD4m/BTwuRNfBvmNXwwul+HO+XQFajZwh7Q/a6doNyWSoc1ZlZj9ZzUVVANSgDxQm5B8Dlcg02sTmsa+JomYQhXXszKrth8MoR2/jmrCcY8dgvM8ElFo099VW92QAeiecpHkTyPUghxV2O5HE/B68K9/DwuMWSoHUDaKTJjpzcaG++pKpLJ3WEiiYVmitXM6N5pgkOhwP8qbOyjP6CdEuYqsJUVCdMNIvKG/Epl72SXutkROH5dW3+OXEnlI5ft9O9a07BGr6n1E/mBO+mjMcxPrjoSzERubBv23Ac4hWeQmP9c8tW4xdDSmODQe+evH0NvMoTs2Q1iaPl4Bn9zqMZ0ccD+pnzC/Qbb1qHNKtYPwDiKQjs)